# Set breakpoint in Eclipse if ojb instance of class

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I have set a breakpoint on entry of a method which takes an Object as an argument. I want to stop conditionally if the object is an instance of a chosen class. In breakpoint preferences I set a condition like

```
obj instanceof FQDN
```

but I get the error `MyClass cannot be resolved to a type`. What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate a hint.

EDIT: I also tried

```
obj instanceof FQDN;
```

and

```
return obj instanceof FQDN;
```

Comment: `MyClass` is the FQN ?

Comment: Sorry for the unspecific question, I updated it.

Comment: This is after you updated it?  The class name referenced in the breakpoint expression has to be a fully-qualified class name, including the package.

Comment: Adding the package resolves the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

did you set the preference LIKE obj instance MyClass

or EXACTLY LIKE obj instance MyClass? Because if you wrote it like that the name of the class should be MyClass, which is bad on it's own but should work. If you simply can't find the classname, try looking up the package name, the debugger may not find the class because the package is not included.

Also, you could simply fork into a endless-while loop or something similar and break inside there.